# Redirect standard input dynamically in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, io-redirection

I was trying to do this to decide whether to redirect stdin to a file or not:

```
[ ...some condition here... ] && input=$fileName || input="&0"
./myScript < $input
```

But that doesn't work because when the variable $input is "&0", bash interprets it as a filename.

However, I could just do:

```
if [ ...condition... ];then
    ./myScript <$fileName
else
    ./myScript
```

The problem is that ./myScript is actually a long command line that I don't want to duplicate, nor do I want to create a function for it because it's not that long either (it's not worth it).

Then it occurred to me to do this:

```
[ ...condition... ] && input=$fileName || input=  #empty
cat $input | ./myScript
```

But that requires to run one more command and a pipe (i.e. a subshell).
Is there another way that's simpler and more efficient?

Comment: It's always worth creating functions.

Comment: Never say "always". Functions add a level of abstraction that's not always desirable.

Comment: Maybe. In this case I think it is desirable.

Comment: Detail nitpick on the bottom line of your code: `cat` in a shell script is almost always superfluous and thus a waste of typing and processor time. Normally you can substitute `./myScript < $input`.

Comment: I can't do that because $input may be empty

Comment: I see. OK then, the function solution looks good.

Comment: Be aware that `eval` has security implications: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First of all stdin is file descriptor 0 (zero) rather than 1 (which is stdout).

You can duplicate file descriptors or use filenames conditionally like this:

```
[[ some_condition ]] && exec 3<"$filename" || exec 3<&0

some_long_command_line <&3
```

Note that the command shown will execute the second `exec` if either the condition is false *or* the first `exec` fails. If you don't want a potential failure to do that then you should use an `if` / `else`:

```
if [[ some_condition ]]
then
    exec 3<"$filename"
else
    exec 3<&0
fi
```

but then subsequent redirections from file descriptor 3 will fail if the first redirection failed (after the condition was true).

Comment: Just what I needed. If I create the new file descriptor inside a function, will it still exist after the function ends?

Comment: Yes, but so will the pointer into the file. In other words, if you seek to the end of the file in the function you will still be there outside the function. `test() { exec 3<inputfile; cat <&3; }; cat <&3` will only output the file once, but you can do `test() { exec 3<inputfile; }; cat <&3`

Comment: This answer is not clear enough. What does each command-line here do?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson If I understand you correctly. `if [[ some_condition ]]
then
    exec <"$filename"
else
    exec <&0
fi` could be a complete solution, it seems there is no meaning to use `exec 3<"$filename"`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

Standard input can also be represented by the special device file `/dev/stdin`, so using that as a filename will work.

```
file="/dev/stdin"
./myscript < "$file"
```

Comment: That sounds like possibly some sort of misconfiguration; `/dev/stdin` should (almost) always be usable.  In particular, I believe Linux and Solaris both implement it as a symlink to `/proc/self/fd/0`, and the only problems I can think of would be if UID has changed.

Comment: Well, so one "common" situation would be: terminal is owned by user A, script is running as user B, stdin is tied to terminal.  Is this what you're doing?

Comment: I logged in as root and then switched to a normal user with `su visit`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, it could; `ls -l \`tty\`` will tell you for sure.  If it's not owned by `visit`, trying to reopen `/dev/stdin` may fail.

Comment: That's the problem then. It's owned by root. Which means I can't rely on this solution since It won't always work (and in my case it will never work as I normally use `su` to test scripts that other users will run)

Answer (score 7):

```
(
    if [ ...some condition here... ]; then
        exec <$fileName
    fi
    exec ./myscript
)
```

In a subshell, conditionally redirect stdin and exec the script.

Comment: +1. Put quotes around `$fileName` in case it contains spaces.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
function runfrom {
    local input="$1"
    shift
    case "$input" in
        -) "$@" ;;
        *) "$@" < "$input" ;;
    esac
}
```

I've used the minus sign to denote standard input because that's traditional for many Unix programs.

Now you write

```
[ ... condition ... ] && input="$fileName" || input="-"
runfrom "$input" my-complicated-command with many arguments
```

I find these functions/commands which take commands as arguments (like `xargs(1)`) can be very useful, and they compose well.

Answer (score 2):

If you're careful, you can use '`eval`' and your first idea.

```
[ ...some condition here... ] && input=$fileName || input="&1"
eval ./myScript < $input
```

However, you say that 'myScript' is actually a complex command invocation; if it involves arguments which might contain spaces, then you must be very careful before deciding to use '`eval`'.

Frankly, worrying about the cost of a '`cat`' command is probably not worth the trouble; it is unlikely to be the bottleneck.

Even better is to design `myScript` so that it works like a regular Unix filter - it reads from standard input unless it is given one or more files to work (like, say, `cat` or `grep` as examples).  That design is based on long and sound experience - and is therefore worth emulating to avoid having to deal with problems such as this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`eval`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-eval-112):

```
#! /bin/bash

[ $# -gt 0 ] && input="'"$1"'" || input="&1"

eval "./myScript <$input"
```

This simple stand-in for `myScript`

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -lp
$_ = reverse
```

produces the following output:

```
$ ./myDemux myScript
pl- lrep/nib/rsu/ !#
esrever = _$

$ ./myDemux
foo
oof
bar
rab
baz
zab
```

Note that it handles spaces in inputs too:

```
$ ./myDemux foo\ bar
eman eht ni ecaps a htiw elif
```

To pipe input down to `myScript`, use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
$ ./myDemux <(md5sum /etc/issue)
eussi/cte/  01672098e5a1807213d5ba16e00a7ad0
```

Note that if you try to pipe the output directly, as in

```
$ md5sum /etc/issue | ./myDemux
```

it will hang waiting on input from the terminal, whereas [ephemient's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987105/bash-redirect-standard-input-dynamically-in-a-script/1987467#1987467) does not have this shortcoming.

A slight change produces the desired behavior:

```
#! /bin/bash

[ $# -gt 0 ] && input="'"$1"'" || input=/dev/stdin
eval "./myScript <$input"
```

Comment: What's the difference between `command1 <(command2)`, `command1 <<<$(command2)` and `command2 | command1` ??

Comment: The first is process substitution, whose documentation is linked above. The second composes command substitution (`$(...)`) with here-string (`<<<`) to send the output of `command2` to the standard input of `command1`. The last goes through the usual fork-exec sequence for running commands but creates a pipe whose write end replaces the standard output of `command2` and whose read end replaces the standard input of `command1`.

Answer (score 0):

people show to you very long scripts, but.... you get bash trap :)
You must quote everything in bash.
for example, you want list file named  &0  .

filename='&0'   #right
ls $filename    #wrong! this substitute $filename and interpret &0
ls "$filename"  #right

another, files with spaces.

filename=' some file with  spaces '
ls $filename  #wrong, bash cut first and last space, and reduce multiple spaces between with and spaces words
ls "$filename"  righ

the same is in your script. please change:

```
./myScript < $input
```

to

```
./myScript < "$input"
```

its all. bash has more traps.
I suggest make quotation for "$file" with the same reason. spaces and other characters than can be interpreted are allways make problems.

but what about /dev/stdin ? this is useable only when you redirected stdin and want to print something to real stdin.

so, your script should show like this:

```
[ ...some condition here... ] && input="$fileName" || input="&0"
./myScript < "$input"
```