# bash redirecting stdin to script

Tags: bash, redirect, pipe, file-descriptor

I went through some bash i/o tutorials but most of them concern redirecting stream to/from files.

My problem is the following: how to redirect stdin/stdout/stderr to script (or program).

For instance I have script "parentScript.sh". In that script I want to call blackbox "childScript.sh" which takes few arguments -arg1 -arg2 ... and reads input from stdin.

My goal is to feed childScript.sh with some input inside parentScript.sh:

```
...
childScript.sh -arg1 -arg2
????? < "input1"
????? < "input2"
...
```

Another case would be I call few programs and I want them to talk to each other like this:

```
...
program1 -arg1 -arg2
program2 -arg1 -arg9
(program1 > program2)
(program2 > program1)
etc...
...
```

How to solve these 2 cases? Thanks

EDIT: 
To be more specific. I would like to make own pipes (named or not named) and use them to connect multiple programs or scripts so they talk to each other.

For instance: program1 writes to program2 and program3 and receives from program2. program2 writes to program1 and program3 and receives from program1. program3 only receives form program1 and program2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987105/bash-redirect-standard-input-dynamically-in-a-script

Comment: Right now, this is arguably too broad. Whether many of the techniques for programmatic pipeline building (such as recursive functions exec'ing components) are applicable depends on details you aren't providing. [Also, "clarifying" a question in a way that dramatically changes its meaning *after answers are already provided* is not particularly good form, as it makes those prior answers useless].

Comment: good point. I'll make new thread

Comment: What exactly is the line `????? < "input1"` supposed to do? Perhaps part of why folks aren't understanding your question is that you're expecting us to intuit your intent from extremely unclear pseudocode.

Comment: It meant ????? to be sth that points to the called script, sth like file descriptor

Answer (score 2):

The pipe `|` is your friend:

```
./script1.sh | ./script2.sh
```

will send stdout from `script1.sh` to `script2.sh`. If you want to send stderr as well:

```
./script1.sh 2>&1 | ./script2.sh
```

And only stderr:

```
./script1.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null | ./script2.sh
```

You can also make here documents:

```
./script2.sh << MARKER
this is stdin for script2.sh.
Variable expansions work here $abc
multiply lines works.
MARKER

./script2.sh << 'MARKER'
this is stdin for script2.sh.
Variable expansions does *not* work here
$abc is literal
MARKER
```

`MARKER` can be practically anything: `EOF`, `!`, `hello`, ... One thing to note though is that there cannot be any spaces / tabs infront of the end marker.

And in bash you can even use `<<<` which works much like here documents, if anyone can clarify it would be much appreciated:

```
./script2.sh <<< "this is stdin for script2.sh"
./script2.sh <<< 'this is stdin for script2.sh'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HEREDOC syntax such as:

```bash
childScript.sh -arg1 -arg2 <<EOT
input1
EOT

childScript.sh -arg1 -arg2 <<EOT
input2
EOT
```

And pipe to make forward the output of first script to input of second:

```bash
program1 -arg1 -arg2 | program2 -arg1 -arg9
```