# constructing pipe topology w/ loops, shared sink

Tags: bash, pipe, file-descriptor

I went through some bash i/o tutorials but most of them concern redirecting stream to/from files.

I would like to make own pipes (named or not named), use file descriptors and use them to connect multiple programs or scripts so they talk to each other.

For instance, to provide an example of a topology this should be able to construct:

- program1 writes to program2 and program3 and receives from program2
- program2 writes to program1 and program3 and receives from program1
- program3 only receives from program1 and program2.

Thus, the topology constructed should look like:

```
prog1 <-----> prog2
     \       /
      \     /
       \   /
        \ /
         V
       prog3
```

Comment: goal is to use numbered file descriptors

Comment: "Writes to program2 and program3" -- via a single FD that's tee'd to both, or separately, with them potentially getting different output?

Comment: This doesn't seem substantially different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37549212/1126841).

Comment: Err. And you say "named or not named", but then you insist on numbered FDs. What's the point of numbered FDs if an answer is using named pipes?

Comment: The problem won't be writing to multiple streams, it will be reading from multiple streams at once.  How do you expect the input to be arranged?  Each input source line at a time?  All jumbled together?

Comment: @chepner, the previous question was "clarified" in a way that made prior answers no longer applicable. Since that's frowned on, the new one was made at my urging.

Comment: @tomtom, ...should program3 be getting the combined input all on one stdin stream? On different descriptors / handles it's written to be able to read? Something else?

Comment: program3 should be getting combined input from both program1 and program2. Depending on message content, programs will wait for each other and take action in synchronous fashion (so there is no way programs 1 and 2 writes to program3 independently)

Comment: @tomtom, ...next question: Which OS? Do we have `/dev/fd` guaranteed to be available?

Comment: @tomtom, ...so, here's the thing: File descriptors don't natively support any kind of fanout. That is, for every write operation, there's exactly one reader who gets what you've fed in. To change that, you need to have another program in the middle, that acts as that one reader and then runs multiple write operations.

Comment: @tomtom, ...however, that program sitting in the middle? What it's doing is inherently, necessarily asynchronous. If you're making assumptions about something that's written being read by two different programs at the exact same time, that assumption absolutely will not hold.

Comment: Hmm what about this scenario: p1 writes few lines to both p2 and p3 (can be sequential, that is line1 goes to p2 then to p3, line2 goes to p2 then to p3 etc..) Then after specific message p1 and p2 switch roles and now p2 does the same thing that p1 did.

Comment: @tomtom, if your programs are *written* to cooperate with each other, why make the shell contort to do the setup itself?

Comment: its required by specification. Need to do it in bash

Comment: ...so this is homework? Bah. This is the part where I kick myself for wasting my time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A topology like this is a bit tricky, but it's possible if you don't need your writes to be synchronous.

---

I strongly suggest avoiding hanging anything mission-critical on this kind of practice. However, on any operating system where `/dev/fd` is available, something akin to the following can be done:

```
mkfifo prog3_in  # create a named pipe
exec 5<>prog3_in # open read/write: this handle will be inherited by subprocesses, allowing
                 # the two tees to both write to the same stream

mkfifo prog1_out
mkfifo prog2_out

# at minimum the first program must be opened in the background, since opening prog1_out
# for write will hang until a reader is available
prog1 5>&- <prog2_out | tee /dev/fd/5 >prog1_out &
prog2 5>&- <prog1_out | tee /dev/fd/5 >prog2_out &
prog3 <&5 5>&- &

exec 5>&-  # parent shell: close FD 5
wait       # ...and wait for children to exit.
```

`tee`, or some equivalent is necessary in any case where a single write is to result in multiple `read`s. (`tee` itself reads from stdin, and then writes to each output specified).

---

That said, if your programs are constructed with this topology in mind, just write them to take named pipe names as arguments, and leave the shell out of it:

```
prog1 --prog1-pipe=pipe1 --prog2-pipe=pipe2 --prog3-pipe=pipe3.1
prog2 --prog1-pipe=pipe1 --prog2-pipe=pipe2 --prog3-pipe=pipe3.2

# just make prog3 responsible for reading from *both* output pipes
prog3 pipe3.1 pipe3.2
```